# Uncaught reference error when I try and make a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

I'm trying to make a constructor for an addition problem generator but when I run my code I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: firstNum is not defined"

```
function GenAddProb()
{
    this.firstNum = returnRandomInt(1,10);
    this.secondNum =  returnRandomInt(1,10);
    this.ans = firstNum+secondNum;
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way my constructor is written? From what I've seen in tutorials I don't have to define firstNum and secondNum as variables before I use them in the constructor.

Comment: `this.ans = firstNum+secondNum;` where you found firstNum and secondNum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this.ans = firstNum+secondNum;

As it says, firstNum is not defined. Did you mean `this.ans = this.firstNum + this.secondNum`?

> From what I've seen in tutorials I don't have to define firstNum and secondNum as variables before I use them in the constructor.

You don't need to define `this`, if that's what you mean. In the context of a constructor, `this` is the object you're constructing. But if you want to create and use local variables, you'll need to define them.

Comment: I see. So I still have to reference what object I'm using even if it's from within the constructor. Changed it to this.ans = this.firstNum + this.secondNum and it works as intended. Thanks for your help!